# Calculate Time difference between two points in the same column (ArcGIS)

Tags: python, time, arcgis, difference

I am trying to calculate the time difference between two points in ArcGIS, using VBScript or Python. I have a dataset of over 10 thousand points. Each has coordinates, dates, and times. I want to create a new field and calculate the time difference in seconds.

The data looks as follows:

FID Shape   N   E   DateTime

0   Point   4768252.94469   4768252.94469   2021/05/06 12:12:05

1   Point   4768245.79949   4768245.79949   2021/05/06 12:12:11

2   Point   4768241.44071   4768241.44071   2021/05/06 12:12:15

3   Point   4768237.3568    4768237.3568    2021/05/06 12:12:18

So, the result with the data showing up would be "6, 4, 3, ...". I would appreciate your help a lot as I have tried many things and none worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it using the [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) module for python.

You can do this:

```
# import module Pandas 
import pandas as pd

# Data as a python Dictionary. Can be imported as CSV too.
data = {
    'N' : ['4768252.94469', '4768245.79949', '4768241.44071', '4768237.3568'],
    'E' : ['4768252.94469', '4768245.79949', '4768241.44071', '4768237.3568'],
    'Time': ['12:12:05','12:12:11','12:12:15','12:12:18']
}
# Creating a Pandas Dataframe object 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# If you want to import the data from CSV use df = pd.read_csv('csvname.csv')
# Converting Time column to datetime object
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
# print the differences
print(df["Time"].diff())
```

output:

```
1   0 days 00:00:06
2   0 days 00:00:04
3   0 days 00:00:03
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I am quite a beginner in programming, so if you can explain this a bit I would appreciate it.

Comment: Hey, I edited the answer with more details and comments.  Since you're dealing with tabular data I recommend using the Pandas module for python especially if you have 10 thousand rows.

Comment: Yes now it's more clear, I'll try this. Thank you a lot

Comment: Hey if the solution worked for you, please consider accepting the answer! cheers!